# Almacenar una imagen en una base de datos SQL Server mediante Razor y web api

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-web-api

Necesito ayuda sobre este tema; quiero almacenar una imagen en la base de datos en SQL Server,  lo que he encontrado es con Web Forms en su mayoría y estoy trabajando con **Razor** y **.NET Core 2.2** mediante una **Web API**. Mi duda es como se puede hacer eso.

Tengo 2 proyectos, uno es el web api y el otro es el razor el cual tiene un javascript que manda la informacion.

La tabla tiene el campo `imgLogo` de tipo `varbinary(MAX)` (Donde quiero almacenar la imagen).

Y este es el codigo del **repository**:

```cs
public async Task<bool> mtdAgregarCompania(string strDescripcion, string strStatus, byte[] imgLogo)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAltaCompania", sql))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@strDescripcion", strDescripcion));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@strStatus", strStatus));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@imgLogo", imgLogo));                       
                        await sql.OpenAsync();
                        await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
                throw new Exception("Error", e);
            }
        }

        private AddCompania MapToValueAddCompania(SqlDataReader reader)
        {
            return new AddCompania()
            {
                intIdCompania = reader["intIdCompania"] == DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt32(0) : (int)reader["intIdCompania"],
                strDescripcion = reader["strDescripcion"].ToString(),
                strStatus = reader["strStatus"].ToString(),
                imgLogo = reader["strStatus"].ToString() //<--- 

            };
        }
```

El **Controller**:

```cs
public AddCompaniaController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString");
        }

        [HttpPost("mtdAgregarCompania")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> mtdAgregarCompania(string strDescripcion, string strStatus, byte[] imgLogo)
        {
            AddCompaniaRepository _repository = new AddCompaniaRepository(_connectionString);
            if (await _repository.mtdAgregarCompania(strDescripcion, strStatus, imgLogo))
            {
                return Ok("Se agrego correctamente");
            }
            else return NotFound();
        }
```

Y esto es el codigo de la **vista razor**:

```html
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AddCompania";
}
    <script type="text" src="~/js/peticionesCompania.js">
    </script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="block-header">
        <h2><strong>Registrar</strong> Compañia</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="body">
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                    <p class="my-2">Nombre de Compañia: *</p>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="txtCompania" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Compañia" minlength="4" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                    <p class="my-2">Status: *</p>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="txtStatus" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="breve descripcion" minlength="4">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 body">
                    <form action="/" id="frmFileUpload" class="dropzone" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="dz-message">
                            <div class="drag-icon-cph"> <i class="material-icons">touch_app</i> </div>
                            <h3 class="m-b-0">Suelte los archivos aquí o haga clic para cargar.</h3>

                        </div>
                        <div class="fallback">
                            <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 align-center">

                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-round" id="btnAgregarC">Agregar <i class="zmdi zmdi-save"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript que envia la informacion al api**:

```
$(function () {
    var rutaServidor = 'https://localhost:44302/api/';
   //EVENTO QUE AL PRECIONAR EL BOTON btnGuardarEmpresa SE REALICE LO QUE ESTE DENTRO DE ESTE
    $("#btnAgregarC").click(function () {
        console.log("Guardando");
        //SE VALIDA QUE NO EXISTAN CAMPOS VACIOS DE ENCONTRARSE UNO VACIO MOSTARÁ UN MENSAJE INFORMATIVO DE LO CONTRARIO REALIZARÁ LA PETICION AJAX PARA REALIZAR UN POST A LA BASE DE DATOS
        if ($("#txtCompania").val() == "" || $("#txtStatus").val() == "" || $("#frmFileUpload").val() == "" ) {
            Swal.fire({
                type: 'error',
                title: 'Campos vacíos',
                text: 'No se puede guardar con campos vacíos'
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Hola, empieza insercion");
            $.ajax({
                //TIPO DE PETICION QUE SE REALIZA
                type: 'POST',
                //URL A DONDE SE CONECTARÁ, EN ESTE CASO LOS PARÁMETROS QUE SE ENVIARÁN AL API NOTA: La variable rutaServidor es invocada desde otro script
                url: rutaServidor + 'Usuarios/mtdInsertarUsuarios?strDescripcion=' + $.trim($("#txtCompania").val())
                    + '&strStatus=' + $.trim($("#txtStatus").val())
                    + '&imgLogo=' + $.trim($("#frmFileUpload").val()),
                dataType: '',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log("hola, si se inserto compañia");
                    //ACCIONES A REALIZARSE EN CASO DE QUE LA PETICION SEA EXITOSA Y MOSTRARÁ UN MENSAJE SUCCESS
                    mtdLimpiarCamposUsuario();                 
                    $("#btnAgregarC").hide();
                    //$("#btnCancelar").hide();
                    Swal.fire({
                        type: 'success',
                        title: 'Agregado Correctamente',
                        text: 'La compañia se agregó correctamente'

                    });
                },
                error: function (x) {
                    console.log("Error");
                    //EN CASO DE TENER UN ERROR MOSTRARÁ UN MENSAJE ERROR
                    Swal.fire({
                        type: 'error',
                        title: 'Agregado Error',
                        text: 'Error en el servidor intente más tarde'
                    });
                },
            });       
        }
    });  
});
```

Comment: Hablas de que estás trabajando con Razor, puedes indicar el código de la Vista Razor?. Y por otra parte, necesitarás un cliente `HttpClient` para consumir el Web  API, podrías indicar el código si lo tienes?.

Comment: De hecho el proyecto razor se comunica con el web api mediante un javascript, el cual envia la informacion al HttpPost "mtdInsertarCompanias".